# Display value (in units) in Heat Map Scale (swimlane/ngx-charts)

Tags: angular, d3.js, ngx-charts

Refer [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2rtX5cueg2hlzmztUbkH?p=preview) url for the demo.

As per the snapshot:

[image]

Data values are coming the same format they are being fetched. It should have option to display in unit:

> like 2140000 to be displayed as 2 GB.

Code Sample:

```js
export class App {

    //single: any[];
    multi: any[];

    // Size to be displayed 
    view: any[] = [1000, 400];

    // options

    showXAxis = true;
    showYAxis = true;
    gradient = false;
    showLegend = true;
    showXAxisLabel = true;
    xAxisLabel = 'Hour';
    showYAxisLabel = true;
    yAxisLabel = 'Days';
}
```

Comment: You probably need to make a feature request on GitHub to do that. The bar is not a proper d3 axis, where you might be able to format the values; it's just a `div` with more `div`s containing text elements at either end. You can use standard DOM manipulation techniques to change it.

Comment: Hi @ialarmedalien,Could you please let me know if I have to raise PR for this. Since I am not sure which function module to be modified for same.

Comment: There isn't a way to do it with the existing API; you would have to manipulate the DOM elements after the chart had been drawn, which is a bit of a hack. I would raise an issue on GitHub about it.

Comment: Hi @ialarmedalien. I have raised one issue .Please refer https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/1013

Comment: Hi @ialarmedalien.Could u please suggest any alternate hack  for this. I have not received any update from library github account